# Show window after notify icon click

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I'm trying to show my form when the user clicks on my notifyicon after the form has been minimized to the system tray. However upon calling Show() the form reappears but is always minimized, i have to click the taskbar icon to un-minimize. Here is my code.

```
        private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                Hide();
            }
        }

        private void notifyIcon1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Show();
            //BringToFront();
        }
```

I've also tried adding BringToFront() but to no avail.

I need noifyIcon click to show the form, but for it not to be minimized afterward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `WindowState` property to `Normal`.

Answer (score 3):

Set your window state back to not minimized. For example :

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Comment: Thanks, i guess I'll give the answer to you since you answered first.

Comment: ElVieejo's answer was the first.

Comment: Actually, my answer was first.  You can see exact timestamps in the tooltips.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```